# Strong Equivalence Principle and Milgrom's Law

Tags: general-relativity, astrophysics, equivalence-principle, modified-gravity

I am reading this paper by [Milgrom(1983)](https://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/pdf/1983ApJ...270..365M) that suggests a modification to Newton's Second Law in order to do away with the requirement of dark matter on astrophysical scales. My question is regarding a paragraph in Section 3 of the paper that says:

> Consider now the question of how an external acceleration affects the internal dynamics of a system. Had
> the SEP been valid in the modified dynamics, there
> would be no such effects at all. If this was the case, the
> rotation curves of galaxies should stay flat to very large
> radii even when these galaxies are accelerated in the
> field of a cluster, say (assuming that tidal effects can be
> neglected). The validity of the SEP would also imply
> that stellar systems with very small internal accelerations ($a_0$) would always exhibit a large mass
> discrepancy when analyzed with the conventional dynamics. The data on open clusters in the solar neighborhood (region H in Fig. 1) appear to be in conflict with
> this result. Jones (1910a, b) finds a dynamically deduced
> mass for the Pleiades and Praesepe which is only about
> a factor 1.5 larger than the mass accounted for by stars
> in these clusters. The internal accelerations in these
> clusters are, however, a few times (5-10) smaller than
> a0, and if the SEP is obeyed by the modified dynamics,
> we would expect a larger mass discrepancy than is
> observed.

I followed the paper until here but unfortunately cannot make of anything from this paragraph. I don't have a specific question in mind, but it would be great to have an answer than explain the conclusions made by Milgrom in finer detail.

Answer (score 1):

Milgrom here is accepting that MOND does not support the strong equivalence principle because MOND would get the masses wrong in these systems, if it did.  Instead, MOND results depend on the total gravity on the system, so physics inside a freely falling system is different if it is freely falling toward something with acceleration greater than some limit.  It is not equivalent to floating freely in space.

But, in my humble opinion, SEP is necessary.  Each atom in a star in the outer parts of a galaxy is undergoing strong gravity from all of the other atoms in the star.  That would mean MOND does not apply to stars (doubly for binary stars) there, but it would apply to the gas there.  However, in reality, the stars and the gas move together quite closely.